# How show textures used shaders and why my way doesnt working?

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk

When I enable shader program, texture doesnt work

*A_andrew is texture in alias (Part of|in Texture2D)*
*alias is alias (Texture2D)*

CSharp Code

```cs
GL.ClearColor(255, 255, 255, 255);
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

A_andrew.Bind();
//shaderProgram.Use(); when enabled texture are disapeare
shaderProgram.GetUniform("texture0").SetVec1(alias.id);

GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
AliasTexture2D tex = Draw.CurrentTexutre;
    
GL.TexCoord2(tex.GetLeftBottom());
GL.Vertex2(-0.6f, -0.4f);

GL.TexCoord2(tex.GetRightBottom()); 
GL.Vertex2(0.6f, -0.4f);

GL.TexCoord2(tex.GetRightTop()); 
GL.Vertex2(0.6f, 0.4f);

GL.TexCoord2(tex.GetLeftTop()); 
GL.Vertex2(-0.6f, 0.4f);

GL.End();
window.SwapBuffers();
```

Fragment Shader

```c
version 330 core
in vec2 texCords;
    
uniform sampler2D texture0;
    
out vec4 color;
    
void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = texture(texture0, texCords);
    color = texColor;
}
```

Vertex Shader

```c
version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 inTexCords;
    
out vec2 texCords;
    
void main()
{
    texCords = inTexCords;
    gl_Position = vec4(inPosition.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

I think problem in Fragment Shader, he dont get texture or|and texture cordinates

Comment: You cannot use a version 330 core vertex shader with `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix fixed function attributes and the fixed function matrix stack with a version 3.30 shader program.

You have to use the built in attributes such as `gl_Vertex` and `gl_MultiTexCoord0` (see [Vertex Attributes](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.20.pdf#page=55&zoom=100,153,309)).

You have to use the the built in uniform variables like `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`. In legacy OpenGL (GLSL 1.20) there are provided built-in uniforms. See [OpenGL Shading Language 1.20 Specification; 7.5 Built-In Uniform State](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.20.pdf#page=56&zoom=100,153,218).
One of them is `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` of type `mat4`, which provides the transformation by the model view and projection matrix. There also exist separated varables `gl_ModelViewMatrix` and `gl_ProjectionMatrix` vor the model view and projection matrix.

Vertex shader:

```c
version 120
 
varying vec2 texCords;
    
void main()
{
    texCords = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

Comment: if problem in glBegin i want to refuse from he What technology i should use for normal texture display

I dont want use glsl version less 3.0

Comment: @NickName73 So you cannot use `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences. I recommend reading a good tutorial. e.g.: [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/)

Comment: @Azarien No. Yo can't use `330`! You have to access the fixed function vertex attribute with `gl_Vertex`!